# Как после прорисовки страницы, занести всё содержимое в переменную и вывести её на jS?

Tags: javascript

Собственное весь вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: Что понимается под "через jS"? И для чего?

Comment: Например у меня стоит виджет ВК на странице. Нужно после его отрисовки, спарсить id пользователя.

Comment: Не получится. Same Origin Policy не даст.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения содержимого элемента в виде простого текста у элементов есть свойство InnerHTML

```
let elem = document.getElementTagName('Body')[0];
text = elem.innerHTML
console.log(text);
```

Поскольку метод getElementTagName возвращает HTMLCollection, а это объект подобный массиву, то нам необходимо обратится к нему по индексу.

Соответственно что бы изменить содержимое элемента, то необходимо присвоить этому свойству новое значение.

Comment: Благодарю. Содержимое iframe не выводится только, хотя в коде страницы все можно прочесть.

Comment: Дело в том что объект iframe представлен другим контекстом исполнения. Он представляет собой отдельный объект window на который можно сослаться по его идентификатору  window.frames[ID], но если родительский документ и дочерний имеют разное происхождение, то сценарии не смогут взаимодействовать друг с другом из-за политики общего происхождения. Теоретически содержимое дочернего фрейма можно получить так text = window.frames['ID'].document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerText

Comment: body это не вся страница. лучше брать 'html'

Comment: text = window.frames['vkwidget1'].document.getElementById('ee').‌​innerText;

console.log(text);

сделал так, в консоле выдало следующее: GET https://top-fwz1.mail.ru/js/code.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log([...document.childNodes].map(node => node.innerHTML).join())
```